# Redimensionar imagem automaticamente

Tags: html, css, imagem, div

Ao programar uma página web via PC adicionei um mapa de imagem cuja imagem era relativamente grande, ocupando a largura da página inteira. O problema é que ao acessar por uma tela menor, como a de um notebook por exemplo, a imagem não redimensiona junto com a div como o restante da página.

Já tentei usar `max-width` e definir o tamanho no `style`da `div`, mas não deu certo.

Este é o código que estou usando:

---

```
<div class="container">
<map name = "shape">
<area shape = "rect" coords = "0, 0, 500, 500" 
href="/31.01.2018/production/ajax/historicoperini1.php"/>
</map>
<img src="\31.01.2018\production\imagem.jfif" usemap="#shape"  />
</div>
```

---

Obs: Linguagem HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que a imagem fique responsiva, ou seja, que se auto-ajusta dentro da `div`, você pode usar uma das alternativas:

Se estiver usando Bootstrap, pode usar a classe `.img-fluid`:

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="\31.01.2018\production\imagem.jfif" usemap="#shape"  />
```

Ou pode usar o atributo `width="100%"`:

```
<img width="100%" src="\31.01.2018\production\imagem.jfif" usemap="#shape"  />
```

Ou definir no CSS:

```
<style>
img{
   width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

**Teste:**

```css
img{
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
   <map name = "shape">
      <area shape = "rect" coords = "0, 0, 500, 500" href="/31.01.2018/production/ajax/historicoperini1.php"/>
   </map>
   <img width="100%" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" usemap="#shape"  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tem uma outra opção, que não sei se vc pode usar assim, mas seria usando a imagem `<img>`que está dentro da `<div class="container">` na forma de background.

Dessa forma por exemplo:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container.imagem{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 33%;
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/900/300);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container imagem">
    <map name = "shape">
        <area shape = "rect" coords = "0, 0, 500, 500" href="/31.01.2018/production/ajax/historicoperini1.php"/>
    </map>
</div>
```

Ou seguindo a mesma ideia, mas com uma `<div>` no lugar da `<img>` e a imagem como sendo o `background` da `<div>`

Dessa forma por exemplo:

```css
.imagem{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/900/300);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <map name = "shape">
        <area shape = "rect" coords = "0, 0, 500, 500" href="/31.01.2018/production/ajax/historicoperini1.php"/>
    </map>
    <div class="imagem"></div>
</div>
```